# MySQL SSH console runs subquery correctly but mysqli returns zero for subquery column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm hesitant to post the entire query but perhaps it's necessary with my variable assignments. In short, the tenth column is a subquery and should return a count of occurrences for something in another table.

**SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3718e/2**

User ID `366` is a test production account. This is normally a dynamically-binded `?` prepared variable. User ID `366` should return two rows. The nine columns aren't important for this question, but the 10th (the subquery) should have a count of `1` and `0` in the first and second rows, respectively. This works on an SSH connection to MySQL. However, PHP's mysqli and even PhpMyAdmin return `0` and `0` respectively. I have sandboxed the PHP so the error is lying in the SQL I believe.

Sample correct output from SSH (9 columns before ignored):

`+--------+
| guests |
+--------+
|      0 |
|      1 |
+--------+`

mysqli will return just zeros. **Other columns are unaffected and SSH/mysqli both agree and return correctly.** If more context is needed, let me know.

Thank you.

---

[image: Screenshot from server]

> `SELECT tickets.id, @formal_id:=schedule.id as 'formal_id',
>   schedule.name, schedule.date, schedule.colour,
>   @li_price:=schedule.livers_in_price as 'li',
>   @lo_price:=schedule.livers_out_price as 'lo',
>   @gu_price:=schedule.guests_price as 'gu', tickets.for_sale as
>   'for_sale', @guest:=(
>       SELECT COUNT(*)
>       FROM billing
>       WHERE guest = 1
>       AND user_id = @user_id
>       AND formal_id = @formal_id ) AS 'guests' FROM tickets JOIN user ON tickets.user_id = user.user_id JOIN schedule ON tickets.formal_id =
>   schedule.id JOIN billing ON tickets.formal_id = billing.formal_id
>   WHERE user.user_id = 366 AND schedule.date > NOW() GROUP BY
>   tickets.id;`

Comment: any chance of a fiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Let me make one, thanks

Comment: Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3718e/2

Comment: i dont know how you get 0,1 i get 0,0

Comment: Screenshot added from server

Comment: yheah this odd, i cant reproduce, but am still trying

Comment: `AND user_id = tickets.user_id` seems to make it work, i suspect its the joins and getting the right 'id' here, let me know

Comment: Hi, I copied another query used elsewhere in the application and I got it working using a similar approach to you, if you want to put it as an answer you can get the points. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without specifying the table source for a variable when joins are in play you can get unexpected results. Using `table.column` syntax will save you a lot of grief.

In this case `AND user_id = tickets.user_id`

but I cant explain the inconsistent results between your testing and mine.